# RC circuit with two voltage sources and finding I(t)

Tags: circuit-analysis, step-response

I would like some guidance on this problem that I have:

This is the circuit:

[image]

And the question is:

[image]

**Note**: typo in the question, closes should be closed.

So my take on the question is:

There is two cases, one t<0 and one t=0. In order for me to find I1 I'm thinking that I need to calculate Vc. So when t<0 the switch has been closed for a long time and the capacitor should act like an open circuit, like this:

[image]

So I'm having a bit of a difficulty to go on because of the two voltage sources. In my mind I'm thinking that when the capacitor acts like an open circuit then VA should not be considered. However I won't be able to calculate Vc by only having VB, R2 and R1.

So my difficulty is what happens when the switch is closed. How am I supposed to find I1 when the switch is closed?

Any suggestions would be kind!

Comment: @Andyaka could you please elaborate how you found it out?

Comment: @Andyaka should I consider VA to be present when the capacitor is acting like an open circuit? Or should I consider the "upper half" of the circuit?

Comment: Va is not considered when the capacitor is charged because it doesn't supply current through the (charged) capacitor hence, you just consider the upper half.

Comment: I originally read the top source as being 1 volt so I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the voltage loops you have:

Loop 1

$$2V - I_{R2}R2-I_{R1}R1=0$$

Loop 2

$$1V - V_{cap} + I_{R1}R1=0$$

At t=0, there's no current flowing into the capacitor because it is already charged, meaning that \$I_{R2}=I_{R1}\$. Rewriting the first loop equation and solving for the current gives:

$$I_{R1}=\dfrac{2V}{R_1+R_2} = 500\mu A$$

Replacing the current in the second equation and solving for the capacitor voltage yields

$$V_{cap} = 1V + 500\mu A \cdot 1k\Omega=1.5V$$

So basically your capacitor will discharge from 1.5V to 1V. The discharging curve can be computed using:

$$V_{CAP, t}=V_{CAP,t=0}e^{\dfrac{-t}{1k\Omega \cdot 500pF}}$$

The rest you can figure out.

Here is a small simulation just to double check it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out. I doubted my skill to calculate because I would get the current to 0.5 mA, not 0.25 mA. Now I'm onboard.

Comment: @Vetenskap yeah sorry about that mistake. +1 for the answer for correcting me.

Comment: @Andyaka No problem, that can happen for everyone. :)

Comment: @vtolention I just need to ask: I get that the inital value for I1 is 0.5 mA, however I cannot really grasp how to calculate I1 after the switch has opened. I'm thinking that the lower half of the circuit is left and that I1(∞) is calculated by VR1/R1 = 0.5 mA, however that doesn't make sense. How did you go on to find I1 after switch opened?

Comment: @Vetenskap \$I_{R1}\$ is time dependent. Since you have an initial condition at t=0, you can calculate it at this point in time. Other than that, you would have to derive it. I guess for t>0 it would be something like \$I_{R1}(t)=\dfrac{V_{CAP}(t) - 1V}{R_1}\$, where \$V_{CAP}(t)\$ is given in my answer. For example, if you set t=0 in the above equation, you would end up again with \$500\mu A\$

Comment: @vtolention I guess Vcap (t) = 1.5e^(-t/tau), am I correct?

Comment: @Vetenskap exactly :-)